# Find High Entropy VA (64-bit ALSR) Incompatibility in Disassembly

Tags: disassembly, windows

Have a 64-bit plugin DLL (no source code) and the host application in an update changed its DLL characteristic to include "[high-entropy 64-bit address space layout randomization (ASLR)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/highentropyva-support-64-bit-aslr?view=vs-2019)" When this is set this causes the add-in to randomly crash. While I have used CFF explorer to remove the DLL characteristic for now to fix the application I am wondering if there is any static analysis techniques could be used on a disassembly to find ASLR incompatibility using tool like IDA Pro, or what such code may look like if come across analysing the application crash dumps.

With WinDbg I can see access violation here due to rbp set to invalid value:

```
uccoext64!GetOutlookViewID+0x46eee:
0000016b`01f75bae 488b4500        mov     rax,qword ptr [rbp] ss:00000000`05cccc50=????????????????
```

Stepping backwards I find this invalid value is set in a different DLL:

```
UcLogging64+0x1ec8:
0000016b`05201ec8 488b6c2438      mov     rbp,qword ptr [rsp+38h] ss:00000029`834f8978=0000000005cccc50
```

This section of code:

```
0:000> uf 0000016b`05201ec8 488b6c2438 
UcLogging64+0x1e40:
0000016b`05201e40 48895c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rbx
0000016b`05201e45 48896c2410      mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbp
0000016b`05201e4a 48897c2418      mov     qword ptr [rsp+18h],rdi
0000016b`05201e4f 4154            push    r12
0000016b`05201e51 4883ec20        sub     rsp,20h
0000016b`05201e55 33ff            xor     edi,edi
0000016b`05201e57 418bd9          mov     ebx,r9d
0000016b`05201e5a 4d8be0          mov     r12,r8
0000016b`05201e5d 488bea          mov     rbp,rdx
0000016b`05201e60 40387928        cmp     byte ptr [rcx+28h],dil
0000016b`05201e64 7423            je      UcLogging64+0x1e89 (0000016b`05201e89)  Branch

UcLogging64+0x1e66:
0000016b`05201e66 8b542450        mov     edx,dword ptr [rsp+50h]
0000016b`05201e6a 488d0d0fd60000  lea     rcx,[UcLogging64!UnifiedClientTrace+0xa480 (0000016b`0520f480)]
0000016b`05201e71 e82afaffff      call    UcLogging64+0x18a0 (0000016b`052018a0)
0000016b`05201e76 4885c0          test    rax,rax
0000016b`05201e79 7403            je      UcLogging64+0x1e7e (0000016b`05201e7e)  Branch

UcLogging64+0x1e7b:
0000016b`05201e7b 8b780c          mov     edi,dword ptr [rax+0Ch]

UcLogging64+0x1e7e:
0000016b`05201e7e f6c304          test    bl,4
0000016b`05201e81 7406            je      UcLogging64+0x1e89 (0000016b`05201e89)  Branch

UcLogging64+0x1e83:
0000016b`05201e83 85ff            test    edi,edi
0000016b`05201e85 7e02            jle     UcLogging64+0x1e89 (0000016b`05201e89)  Branch

UcLogging64+0x1e87:
0000016b`05201e87 ffcf            dec     edi

UcLogging64+0x1e89:
0000016b`05201e89 448b442450      mov     r8d,dword ptr [rsp+50h]
0000016b`05201e8e 448bcf          mov     r9d,edi
0000016b`05201e91 498bd4          mov     rdx,r12
0000016b`05201e94 488bcd          mov     rcx,rbp
0000016b`05201e97 e834fcffff      call    UcLogging64+0x1ad0 (0000016b`05201ad0)
0000016b`05201e9c f6c301          test    bl,1
0000016b`05201e9f 7422            je      UcLogging64+0x1ec3 (0000016b`05201ec3)  Branch

UcLogging64+0x1ea1:
0000016b`05201ea1 33c0            xor     eax,eax
0000016b`05201ea3 488bfd          mov     rdi,rbp
0000016b`05201ea6 4883c9ff        or      rcx,0FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFh
0000016b`05201eaa 66f2af          repne scas word ptr [rdi]
0000016b`05201ead 488b053c890000  mov     rax,qword ptr [UcLogging64!UnifiedClientTrace+0x57f0 (0000016b`0520a7f0)]
0000016b`05201eb4 488947fe        mov     qword ptr [rdi-2],rax
0000016b`05201eb8 488b0539890000  mov     rax,qword ptr [UcLogging64!UnifiedClientTrace+0x57f8 (0000016b`0520a7f8)]
0000016b`05201ebf 48894706        mov     qword ptr [rdi+6],rax

UcLogging64+0x1ec3:
0000016b`05201ec3 488b5c2430      mov     rbx,qword ptr [rsp+30h]
0000016b`05201ec8 488b6c2438      mov     rbp,qword ptr [rsp+38h]
0000016b`05201ecd 488b7c2440      mov     rdi,qword ptr [rsp+40h]
0000016b`05201ed2 4883c420        add     rsp,20h
0000016b`05201ed6 415c            pop     r12
0000016b`05201ed8 c3              ret
```

Using Time Travel debugging and a memory write breakpoint on this location I see it seems to change here, stepping backwards:

```
UcLogging64+0x1e45:
0000016b`05201e45 48896c2410      mov     qword ptr [rsp+10h],rbp ss:00000029`834f8978=0000016b0520add8
0:000> r rbp
rbp=0000000005cccc50
```

Looking again for when rbp is set to this:

```
UcLogging64+0x1193:
0000016b`05201193 488b6c2448      mov     rbp,qword ptr [rsp+48h] ss:00000029`834f8958=0000000005cccc50
```

Stepping back:

```
UcLogging64+0x108a:
0000016b`0520108a 56              push    rsi
0:000> dd 00000029`834f8958
00000029`834f8958  05cccc50 00000000 834f8a09 00000029
00000029`834f8968  052051a4 0000016b 0520a728 0000016b
00000029`834f8978  0520add8 0000016b 834f89e0 00000029
00000029`834f8988  6d5e0000 00000000 000004e0 53282064
00000029`834f8998  01f92a80 0000016b 0520a728 0000016b
00000029`834f89a8  0520f0a0 0000016b ffffff01 ffffffff
00000029`834f89b8  01f92a70 0000016b 00000027 00000000
00000029`834f89c8  834fa670 00000029 fffffffe ffffffff
0:000> t-
Time Travel Position: 6516CD:1B [Unindexed] Index
UcLogging64+0x1085:
0000016b`05201085 48896c2420      mov     qword ptr [rsp+20h],rbp ss:00000029`834f8958=0000016b01fad918
0:000> dd 00000029`834f8958
00000029`834f8958  01fad918 0000016b 834f8a09 00000029
```

Going backwards again see this change to invalid instuction on pop rbp:

```
rbp=00000029834f8930
0:000> t-
Time Travel Position: 6516CB:134 [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vswprintf_l+0xd7:
00000000`6d61400f 4883c450        add     rsp,50h
0:000> r rbp
rbp=00000029834f8930
0:000> t
Time Travel Position: 6516CB:135 [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vswprintf_l+0xdb:
00000000`6d614013 5d              pop     rbp
0:000> t
Time Travel Position: 6516CB:136 [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vswprintf_l+0xdc:
00000000`6d614014 c3              ret
0:000> r rbp
rbp=0000000005cccc50
```

As the value was corrupt before function started:

```
Time Travel Position: 6516CA:B51 [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vswprintf_l+0x13:
00000000`6d613f4b 55              push    rbp
0:000> t-
Time Travel Position: 6516CA:B50 [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vswprintf_l+0xf:
00000000`6d613f47 4c896020        mov     qword ptr [rax+20h],r12 ds:00000029`834f8958=0000000000000004
0:000> r rbp
rbp=0000000005cccc50
```

This gets setup in a previous msvcr100!vswprintf_l call:

```
MSVCR100!vsnprintf_l+0xbb:
00000000`6d613a0b 488b6c2468      mov     rbp,qword ptr [rsp+68h] ss:00000029`834f8938=0000000005cccc50
0:000> r rbp
rbp=0000000000000000
0:000> t
Time Travel Position: 6516CA:ACB [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vsnprintf_l+0xc0:
00000000`6d613a10 488b742470      mov     rsi,qword ptr [rsp+70h] ss:00000029`834f8940=0000016b01fad918
0:000> r rbp
rbp=0000000005cccc50
```

This is setup earlier:

```
0:000> r rbp
rbp=0000000005cccc50
0:000> t
Time Travel Position: 6516CA:11C [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vsnprintf_l+0x3:
00000000`6d613953 48895808        mov     qword ptr [rax+8],rbx ds:00000029`834f8930=0000016b0520f0a0
0:000> t
Time Travel Position: 6516CA:11D [Unindexed] Index
MSVCR100!vsnprintf_l+0x7:
00000000`6d613957 48896810        mov     qword ptr [rax+10h],rbp ds:00000029`834f8938=0000016b0520f000
0:000> t
```

This continues, I haven't traced all the way back to origin yet, I am wondering if there is some other way I could find likely code to create this problem.